# C++ - Identify derived class from base class pointer at runtime

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm experimenting with state machines and the one that I'm trying to implement uses function pointers to represent states

```
typedef void (*State)(Signal const&)

class StateMachine
{
public:
    void exampleState(Signal const&);
private:
    State m_currentState;
}
```

Basically, I want to derive a separate class for each signal and in each state function the state machine must be able to determine which kind of signal has been received and execute the corresponding code. A solution that I came up with is something like

```
class Signal {};
class MySignal: public Signal {};

void StateMachine::exampleState(Signal const& signal){
    if (typeid(signal) == typeid(MySignal)){
        //code here
    }
    // other cases...
}
```

First of all I'm not sure that using typeid this way is good practice. Also, this only works if Signal has at least one virtual function.

Another solution would be to define a sort of type flag like an enum, and pass the corresponding one in the derived signal constructor

```
enum signalType{
  mySignalType
  //other types
}

class Signal {
public:
  Signal(signalType sig_type):m_type(sig_type){};
  const signalType m_type;
};

class MySignal: public Signal {
public:
  MySignal():Signal(mySignalType){};
};

void StateMachine::exampleState(Signal const& signal){
  switch (signal.m_type){
    case mySignalType:
      //code here
      break;
    // other cases...
  }
}
```

althoug this requires the enum to be extended each time a new signal class is written.

Is there a more elegant way of achieving this? Or maybe another technique that avoids this check at all? I remember having this problem in other scenarios as well, that's why the question in the title is more general than the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dynamic_cast` instead of `typeid`:

```
class Signal {
public:
    virtual ~Signal() {}
};

class MySignal: public Signal {};

void StateMachine::exampleState(Signal const& signal){
    if (dynamic_cast<MySignal const *>(&signal)){
        //code here
    }
    // other cases...
}
```

Comment: Probably the best option, although this also works only if the class has a virtual table

Comment: @dr.umma which it should, since you should have a virtual destructor when making a hierarchy of classes

Answer (score 3):

What you want to achieve can be done through polymorphism.

Declare a method (or abstract method) in `Signal`, and implement it in `MySignal`:

```
class Signal {
public:
    virtual void my_method() const = 0;
};

class MySignal: public Signal {
public:
    void my_method() const override {
        // do something
    }
};
```

then call your method in `exampleState`, this will call the implemented method:

```
void StateMachine::exampleState(Signal const& signal){
    signal.my_method();
}
```

Comment: The action associated with a signal is state dependent. The nice thing about function pointers in state machines is that you don't have to ckeck the current state. Simply call the current state function and that contains everything. Using this method I have to check my state with a (possibly) long switch statement in each `my_method()` implementation. Or am I missing something?

Comment: in your `exampleState` method, you could call a different `Signal` method based on your state, isn't that what you want? For example if `Signal` has 2 methods `update` and `render`, you would call those methods based on your state. But you don't really care about their implementation, it will depends on how you implemented those methods in the classes that inherit from `Signal`. You could have a render cube, or a render sphere for example, but the state is 'render'.

Comment: If I do this I need to declare a method in the class `Signal` for each state, which is basically a copy of the `StateMachine` interface, and these methods must be defined in each derived class (i.e. if two signals need the same functionality in the same state I need the same code twice). In addition to that, it would move state machine functionalities to the `Signal` class which is not what I want. `Signal` is only supposed to notify that something has happened and possibly store some data.